# How to Sync Menu, Widgets and other masters from Main Website to its Sub Site

Tags: categories, multisite, menus, widgets, options

I am using Wordpress Multisite Network and i am having problems regarding masters to its subsite. I am not able to see the widgets or Menus which were created on Main website to its Sub-site. When i am going to check in the Database whole tables are different of every subsite. So is there any way to Sync Masters like category, Widgets, Menu, Settings etc of Sub-site to its Main Website. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your subsites are not connected per default. Did you already stumble upon functions like [wp_get_sites()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites) or [switch_to_blog()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)?

Comment: yes @Sven do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

That's an old question, if someone like me landed on this page and want some-sort of custom solution for WORDPRESS MULTISITE MENU sharing across all network sites,

Not only menu you can use the same method to share anything other then widgets across all the network sites.

here is the solution : Edit your Header.php

```
//store the current blog_id - Use this function at the start of the function that you want to share

global $blog_id;
$current_blog_id = $blog_id;

//switch to the main blog which will have an id of 1
switch_to_blog(1);

//output the WordPress navigation menu - incase of menu-sharing use this

wp_nav_menu( 
   //add your arguments here
);

//switch back to the current blog being viewed - before ending of the function

switch_to_blog($current_blog_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

On default is each site in the network a single site in the context, menu, settings, widgets. But you can sync about custom source or plugins, like

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multisite-mirror/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-wpmu-sitewide-options/

Also you can use the [Multilingual Press](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) plugin. This have a API fit synchronization about the sites, there habe a relationship between different sites.

Comment: Thnx for replying @bueltge. I am using above plugins now. Hope i'll succeed on this.

Comment: I implemented yd-wpmu-sitewide-options plugin. But when i create new sub-site and click to visit that sub-site, "Whoops! Page Not Found" error occurs.

Comment: More a question for the support forum of the plugin, maybe a bug.

Comment: Ok. Thnx @bueltge